# How to send data from client to server in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, meteor, server

I'm working on one app and have faced one problem. I have HTML page in './public' folder. In './public/js' I have a script that collects some data after filling the form on this page. Then I need to send this data to a server, where some calculations with this data will be done. After this server should send the data back so I can display it on HTML result page. The idea is that I need to hide this code from the client.

Any ideas how it can be done?

EDIT: Got an idea how it can be realized.

In server/main.js I have WebApp.connectHandlers. Also I use connect-route package. So I need to create post xhr in public/example.js and put values in it. the url should be '/someurl' the same as in router.get('/someurl', .....), right?
How can it be done correctly?

Here's some code from server/main.js what I have now:

```
    WebApp.connectHandlers.use(connectRoute(function (router) {
      router.get('/example', staticFile(process.cwd() + '/../web.browser/app' + 'example.html'))
```

The thing is I get some values from form in example.html with .js file stored in /public. Then I create xhr post request and indicate url that should go as the first arg in router.get() in server/main.js.

Fragment of /public/example.js code:

```
    const values = document.querySelector("input").value  //example of some data from form
    const xhr = new XHRHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('POST', '/someurl')
    xhr.send(values)
```

And now I need to get this request in server/main.js, but I can't use router.get('/example',.....) twice on one url. I mean it won't work like this:

```
    WebApp.connectHandlers.use(connectRoute(function (router) {
      router.get('/example', staticFile(process.cwd() + '/../web.browser/app' + 'example.html'))
      router.get('/example', (req, res, next) {...});
```

Probably I'm not right about it but haven't found out yet how it works. So what can I do now?

Comment: Can you add some code please? What data do you want to exactly hide from the client?

Comment: @Jankapunkt look, I have example.html in ./public. Also I have example.js in ./public. In example.html there is a form with fields to input some numbers. In example.js I get values of what I write in input fields and create an object to store these values. Then I want to use the values in a formula to get result. The formula should be hidden, so I'm trying to hide it.

Comment: Please add the code, it's really hard o grasp without any code.

Comment: @Jankapunkt put some code and came up with an idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: May I ask why your HTML and JS are in the `public` folder? This makes it beyond the reach of most of the advantages of using Meteor. Have you considered using one of the supported front ends like Blaze or React?

Comment: @BartS I got the project to work with and the file structure. With the help of WebApp .html pages can be reached through some url. I got a clue, that backend code that should be hidden from the client should be somehow added through router.get(), so I try to know how to do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on this problem and solved it. In server/main.js I add this code:

```
router.post('/method/example', (req, res, next) => {
    let data = '';
    req.on("data", chunk => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      const result = dataHandler(data);
      res.write(`${result}`);
      res.end();
    });
}
```

And in /public/example.js I just did an xhr post request with the same URL as in new line in server/mains.js. And here's how it looks like:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', '/method/example');
xhr.send(data);
xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const reqResult = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html

```
Meteor.call("yourMethodName", (err, result) => {
  // Put your code to update HTML with result
});
```

Also probably a bad idea to have your html in the public folder if you want to use Meteor.call.

Comment: This will not work because their JS is also in the public folder and so won't have access to the `Meteor` object or a connection to the server